# Laravel Query Builder - group by and sum

Tags: laravel, laravel-query-builder

I want to get a list of user activities.
But it should give me back only the 5 users, which have the most activities and a col with the sum of the activities ordered by sum of activities DESC.

```
$now = Carbon::now();
$lastWeekMonday = Carbon::now()->subWeek(1)->startOfWeek()->toDateString();
$mondayThisWeek = Carbon::now()->startOfWeek()->toDateString();

$userActivitiesLastWeek = DB::table('useractions')
    ->select('id', 'comment', 'created_user', 'created_at')
    ->where('created_at', '>=', $lastWeekMonday )
    ->where('created_at', '<', $mondayThisWeek )
    ->get();
```

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `withCount` Query Builder function to get the count of particular relationship.

And then you can order by that count and use the `take` Collection function to take desired number of items from a collection. In your case, 5.

```php
$now = Carbon::now();
$lastWeekMonday = Carbon::now()->subWeek(1)->startOfWeek()->toDateString();
$mondayThisWeek = Carbon::now()->startOfWeek()->toDateString();

$uses = User::with('activities')
            ->withCount('activities')
            ->where('created_at', '>=', $lastWeekMonday )
            ->where('created_at', '<', $mondayThisWeek )
            ->get()
            ->sortByDesc('activities_count')
            ->take(5);
```